# Testing on some basic example in trying to better understand about .padded_batch in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a data a very simple one to test on my understanding about the usage of tf.padded_batch

text file is saved as .txt format:

```
test = "I use tensorflow for this data\n
I will be testing\n
The current tensorflow data
```

Please do mark that I am using tensorflow version 2.0 so I do not need to use tf.Session to initialize my variables

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("test.txt")
dataset = dataset.map(lambda string: tf.string_split([string]).values)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(2)

for x in dataset:
    print(x.numpy())
```

Error that I received:

```
TypeError: padded_batch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'padded_shapes'
```

Expected output:

```
[[b'I' b'use' b'tensorflow' b'for' b'this' b'data']
 [b'I' b'will' b'be' b'testing' b'unknown' b'unknown']]
[[b'The' b'current' b'tensorflow' b'data' b'unknown' b'unknown']]
```

How should I configure my padded_shapes and also padded_values? I wish to make the length of the tensor to be the same by insert "unknown" for each empty element. (This might be a little confused by above shows my expected results.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `tf.data.Dataset().dataset.padded_batch` expects the shape of your inputs, and in your case, since you want the padded value to be `"unknown"` the padding value that you will use. Below is the code snipped you want to use.

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("test.txt")
dataset = dataset.map(lambda string: tf.string_split([string]).values)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(3, padded_shapes=[None], padding_values="unknown")

for x in dataset:
    print(x.numpy())

# [[b'I' b'use' b'tensorflow' b'for' b'this' b'data']
#  [b'I' b'will' b'be' b'testing' b'unknown' b'unknown']
#  [b'The' b'current' b'tensorflow' b'data' b'unknown' b'unknown']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Now I understand it